# SwiftUI Facebook SDK : App ID not found. Add a string value with your app ID for the key FacebookAppID to the Info.plist

Tags: facebook, swiftui, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have added the the correct Facebook sdk values into info.plist as the Quick Start guide shows & added the SDK using the package manager, but I still get this error

`Thread 1: App ID not found. Add a string value with your app ID for the key FacebookAppID to the Info.plist or call [FBSDKSettings setAppID:]`.

The app Id is 100% correct & it is in my info.plist. If I set the name & app Id in my app delegate I just get this error instead:

`Thread 1: fbappid is not registered as a URL scheme. Please add it in your Info.plist`

It seems as though the Facebook SDK can't find any values in my info.plist?

```xml
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>fb823445029398455</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>FacebookAppID</key>
    <string>823445029398455</string>
    <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
    <string>vertoo-dev</string>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fbapi20130214</string>
        <string>fbapi20130410</string>
        <string>fbapi20130702</string>
        <string>fbapi20131010</string>
        <string>fbapi20131219</string>
        <string>fbapi20140410</string>
        <string>fbapi20140116</string>
        <string>fbapi20150313</string>
        <string>fbapi20150629</string>
        <string>fbapi20160328</string>
        <string>fbauth</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
    </array>
```

[This is a screenshot of my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phhuW.png)

Comment: Hi @Andrew did you solve it? I'm facing same issue

Answer (score 27):

Add this in new file

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
        // Initialize Facebook SDK
        FBSDKCoreKit.ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
            application,
            didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions
        )
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @احمد الكردي I am still wondering why my code works before without initializing FB SDK ... and after changing FBAppid its need to init the FB SDK ... any way this is working fine for me now ... you save my ass

Comment: In Objective C:

#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
[[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                           didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

Answer (score 7):

*Tested in Xcode 12.5*

make an **AppDelegate.swift** and add this code below.

```
import SwiftUI
import FacebookCore

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }
    
    func application(_ app: UIApplication,
                     open url: URL,
                     options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        return ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)
    }
}
```

next in your @main App file add this line

```
 @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue because I forgot to add `fb` as prefix of App Id in URL Schemes.

Make sure that you've added like this `fb{app_id}` into url schemes like image below.

[image]

*Navigation to here: Project Navigator > Select Your Target > Info > URL Types*

Answer (score 2):

you should initialize sdk on start, as stated here

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/issues/1745

The other answers do that, but they make you use UIApplicationDelegate from UIKit.  If you want to just do it from swiftui, just add onappear on your contentview in your app file:

```
var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .onAppear(){
                    ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(UIApplication.shared, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: nil)
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

in SwiftUI

1- make sure that the file name is Info.plist - with capital "I".

2-if you faced an error says "Multiple commands produce....Info.plist",

Solution:

Open target -> Build phases > Copy Bundle Resources and remove Info.plist from there.