# Xcode 13 cannot find FacebookAppID when implementing Firebase auth in SwiftUI

Tags: firebase, facebook, swiftui

A major change in Xcode 13 is that `info.plist` is no longer visible. According to Facebook's documentation, I need to add the following to `info.plist`:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
  <dict>
  <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
  <array>
    <string>fbAPP-ID</string>
  </array>
  </dict>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>APP-ID</string>
<key>FacebookClientToken</key>
<string>CLIENT-TOKEN</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>APP-NAME</string>
```

I tried to manually add these in under `Targets -> Info` setting of the project.
[image]

However, whenever I click on the log in button on my app, I got a runtime error that says

```
Thread 1: "App ID not found. Add a string value with your app ID for the key FacebookAppID to the Info.plist or call [FBSDKSettings setAppID:]."
```

[image]

Everything else seems to work (I can see the Facebook default button on my screen).

[image]

### My Facebook Login View

```swift
import SwiftUI
import FacebookLogin

struct CoverView: View {
    @AppStorage("isLoggedIn") var isLoggedIn = false
    @AppStorage("email") var email = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        FBLog(isLoggedIn: $isLoggedIn, email: $email)
            .frame(height: 50)
            .padding(.horizontal, 35)
            .clipShape(Capsule())
    }
}

struct FBLog: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return FBLog.Coordinator(parent1: self)
    }
    
    
    @Binding var isLoggedIn: Bool
    @Binding var email: String
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> FBLoginButton {
        let button = FBLoginButton()
        button.delegate = context.coordinator
        return button
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: FBLoginButton, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
    
    
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, LoginButtonDelegate {
  

        var parent: FBLog
        
        init(parent1: FBLog) {
            parent = parent1
        }

    
        
        func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBLoginButton, didCompleteWith result: LoginManagerLoginResult?, error: Error?) {
            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            
            // check if user cancelled the flow.
            
            if !result!.isCancelled {
                parent.isLoggedIn = true
                let request = GraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "email"])
                request.start() { [self] (_, res, _) in
                    
                    guard let profileData = res as? [String: Any] else {return}
                    
                    // save email
                    parent.email = profileData["email"] as! String
                    
                }
            }
        }
        
        func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBLoginButton) {
            // logging out
            parent.isLoggedIn = false
            parent.email = ""
        }
              
    }
}
```

### Question

How do I correctly implement Facebook auth in SwiftUI using Xcode 13?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found an answer that worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67900140/4784433

> Tested in Xcode 12.5
>
> make an AppDelegate.swift and add this code below.
>
> ```
> import SwiftUI import FacebookCore
>
> class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
>     func application(_ application: UIApplication,
>                      didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
>         ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
>     }
>     
>     func application(_ app: UIApplication,
>                      open url: URL,
>                      options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
>         return ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)
>     } }
> ```
>
> next in your @main App file add this line
>
> `@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate`